# Make grid width same as listview in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, grid, datatemplate

I'd like to have grid width same as listview width, right now it looks like:

[image]

But what i want to reach is:
[image]

Code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Shared">
            <ListView Name="_lv"  ItemsSource="{Binding lista}">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding name}"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <telerik:RadNumericUpDown Name="minRNUD" Value="0" />
                                    <Button Width="40" Height="40" Style="{StaticResource MButton}" Margin="0" Padding="1">
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Image Source="/myProject;component/Pictures/clr.png" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Button.Content>
                                    </Button>
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the parent control for the same, try setting HorizontalContentAlignment on the parent listbox etc.

Answer (score 1):

[HorizontalContentAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) property determines the horizontal alignment of the content

setting HorizontalContentAlignment on the list items may affect it's content not the item itself

however setting the same on the parent items control like ListBox, ListView etc. will affect the alignment of their content or can say the items

so simply moving the HorizontalContentAlignment property to the parent ItemsControl (ListBox, ListView etc). will ensure the desired alignment of the items.

so simply add the property `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to the parent items control of the desired item.